# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - on windows server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, trust

I've a Windows Service developed in .NET (framework 4.8), and I get the "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error when I try to download some website feeds, for example https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/tips.xml

It works on my dev machine (windows 10), but not on my server (windows server 2012).

I've read a lot of things, in particular : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls, so I upgraded my code to .NET 4.8, I tried to set some registry keys (like SchUseStrongCrypto), set Tls12 in code ( ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;) but still the same error...

I also used [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) tool and all is checked...

I don't know what I can do more...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have an almost identical set up (Framework 4.8/Server 2012R2), but getting the same error.

Comment: no I didn't find any solution... :(